# Parsing JSON from remote database to Android ListView

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have managed to created a JSON endpoint on my website. This JSON is fed into my android project,parsed and stored in a list view. The issue i'm having is that, rather than printing each JSON object in each element of the list, a JSON object is being added - making each element of the list longer.

**An example of the list:**

Data1

Data1 Data2

Data1 Data2 Data3

Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4

**I am looking for:**

Data1

Data2

Data3

My code is as follows, could anybody please be so kind as to point out where I may be going wrong?

```
public void setTextToTextView(JSONArray jsonArray){
        String s = "";
        CharSequence news_title = getResources().getText(R.string.news_title);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.simplerow,R.id.rowTextView, arrayList);
        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonResponse;
            try {
                jsonResponse = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                s = s +
                        Html.fromHtml(news_title.toString())
                        +jsonResponse.getString("subject")+"\n"+
                        "Posted By :"+jsonResponse.getString("postedby")+"\n"+"\n";
                arrayList.add(s);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.e("JSON Response:", arrayList.toString());
        arrayAdapter.add(s);
        this.newsResponseListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable `s` is global inside the method `setTextToTextView()` and you are using it in loop as :

```
 s = s + Html.fromHtml(news_title.toString())
                        +jsonResponse.getString("subject")+"\n"+
                        "Posted By :"+jsonResponse.getString("postedby")+"\n"+"\n";
```

Therefore it appends previous data to next data.

What should I change?

Just remove `String s` (first declaration) and write this inside loop:

```
     String s =Html.fromHtml(news_title.toString())
                            +jsonResponse.getString("subject")+"\n"+
                            "Posted By :"+jsonResponse.getString("postedby")+"\n"+"\n";
     arrayList.add(s);
```

Comment: Thanks @VVJ, I don't know how I didn't notice that!